# Use jQuery to remove an inline style

Tags: jquery, css

```
<div class="mydiv">
  <ul style="height:111px; width:222px;">
    ...
```

Is it possible with jQuery (or plain javascript) to remove just the height attribute? Note that there are several instances of .mydiv ul with varying heights.

Answer (score 23):

To remove an attribute, use this:

```
$(".mydiv UL").css("height", "");
```

Thanks to [am not i am](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1106925/am-not-i-am) for correcting my answer.

Comment: +1 for right concept, but should be: `$(".mydiv ul").css("height", "auto");`. You're referencing an id, where should be a class.

Comment: And a live example as I was about to post the same answer: http://jsfiddle.net/cNTD4/

Comment: That doesn't remove the style. The CSS may have a different definition for  the `height`. You should do `.css("height", "");`, which will render the style removed.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Fixed the sytax error (up too late ;)
I was actually needing this function on document ready.  Setting the height to auto seems to work...In fact, I just stumbled upon this but of css that does the same thing
    `div.mydiv ul[style] {
      height: auto !important
    }`

Comment: It's good advice but -1 as it's incorrect that you can't remove the style...see @am not i am's comment.

Comment: @amnotiam thanks - I didn't realise that worked. I've updated my answer and given you credit.

Comment: Just IMHO, but it's best to preserve your original answer and update it with more information rather than completely replacing it...it preserves the logic of the comments so future readers can understand whats going on.

Answer (score 3):

Yes! You can!

If you set the css property to a blank value, it clears it.

So, if your inline style is "background: pink" you can remove it via:

```
$element.css('background','')
```

I'm pretty sure I learned that somewhere here on SE but, alas, don't have the specific source to site, so apologies for not being able to give credit where credit is due.

UPDATE:

Well, I suppose I should have gone to the source. From the jQuery documentation (emphasis mine):

> Setting the value of a style property to an empty string — e.g. $('#mydiv').css('color', '') — removes that property from an element if it has already been directly applied, *whether in the HTML style attribute*, through jQuery's .css() method, or through direct DOM manipulation of the style property. It does not, however, remove a style that has been applied with a CSS rule in a stylesheet or  element.

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: this does not appear to work with .css('height', '') http://jsfiddle.net/U7rHU/1/

Comment: @jbabey it's working just fine for me (stick a background color on your UL to see it work)

Comment: background color is irrelevant, it does not work with the height attribute.

Comment: @jbabey go to your fiddle and give the div a background color. Now comment out your JS. You will see your div is 100 or so pixels tall. Now uncomment your JS. You will see your div now collapses since JS removed the height style. If that's not working, then you have issues with your browser/JS. It's working fine for me in firefox. (Background color is irrelevant to the code, but relevant to you being able to see what's happening)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$('.mydiv ul').height('');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is .. dpeneding on how you'd like to do it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changestyle(element) {
        var currentstyle = document.getElementById(element).style.display;
        if (currentstyle == "inline") {
            document.getElementById(element).style.display = "";
            } else {
            document.getElementById(element).style.display = "inline";
        }
    }
</script>
```

this may vary slightly for different broswers but it should show you how to change it if you want.

eek .. disregard .. jquery - much easier :)

Answer (score 0):

add your style attribute to CSS and then you can add or remove class with these jQuery functions:
[addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

Comment: It's good advice, but doesn't answer the actual question the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.mydiv ul').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('style', $(this).attr('style').replace('height: ', 'height:').replace('height:'+$(this).css('height')+';', '')); 
});
```

just make sure the style value format either `"height:111px;"` or `"height: 111px;"`