# How to remove inline styling in html using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible using jQuery to remove any styles applied to an HTML not via CSS or the style attribute, for example here:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0">
```

I'd like to remove width, border, cellSpacing & cellPadding.

I've seen this post here: [Use jQuery to remove an inline style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790795/use-jquery-to-remove-an-inline-style) but it only does that for a specific attribute plus it seems to apply it using the style attribute and not remove inline ones.

EDIT: I don't want to remove anything that has been applied using the style attribute I want to remove anything that hasn't been applied using it
Thanks

Comment: check my answer with demo

Comment: Seems a little weird. CSS rules should take precedence over the table attributes.

Comment: ...you'd like to remove everything that hasn't got inline styles? Your question is certainly confusing. I can see from the answers that what you want is actually **remove any table styles defined using attributes but keep inline styles if they exist**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Previous answers are stating exactly what you **didn't** want.

**not via CSS or the style attribute. I'd like to remove width, border, cellSpacing & cellPadding.**

```
$('*').removeAttr('width border cellSpacing cellPadding'); // etc
```

Comment: Thanks but I'd like this applied to all elements and all attributes, do I need to specify each one?

Comment: Updated my answer to allow for all elements on page.

Comment: No problem - we got there in the end :)

Comment: Hang on. $('*').removeAttr('border') works but if I add another attribute like: $('*').removeAttr('border, width) it doesnt. Any ideas? I'm testing this with IE8

Comment: Try without the comma. My bad.

Comment: @Joly it works with comma check my answer and demo .

Comment: Yep thanks :) perhaps you can amend your answer so that other people could use it properly

Answer (score 10):

check this one

```
$('#myElement').removeAttr('style');
```

Comment: EDIT: I don't want to remove anything that has been applied using the style attribute I want to remove anything that hasn't been applied using it

Comment: Yours looks better :) +1

Comment: @Joly you are talking about removing inline elements. All inline elements will be in the `style` attribute.

Comment: Sorry so probably used the wrong phrasing, apologise, I have amended the question

Comment: No, they won't. You can have a "width" on a table tag etc. This is still all valid HTML.

Comment: you can try as like ChrisDixon said above,. just like `$('*').removeAttr('width, border, cellSpacing, cellPadding.');`

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
$('#myElement').removeProp('style');
```

[removeProp](http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/)

**Updated after OP updated question**

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/bAcSF/)

```
$('#myElement').removeAttr('border');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/bAcSF/1)

```
$('#myElement').removeAttr('border width cellSpacing cellPadding');
```

If you want to remove attributes from all elements

`$('*').removeAttr('border width cellSpacing cellPadding');`

and list attributes to be removed inside `removeAttr('')`

Comment: Thanks. Can I do this for all html elements on the page?

Comment: @Joly yes you can do it `$('*').removeAttr('border width cellSpacing cellPadding');` and list attributes to be removed inside `removeAttr('')`