# How to make jquery.show() set display to something other than 'block'

Tags: jquery, display

I'm working on a single-page web app, so I have lots of HTML div's with associated CSS rules that set "display: none;"  Depending on what the user does, I use something like $('#some-id').css('display', 'block') to set the display to something other than "none".  This makes the div visible, and all is well.

But it's ugly, because my JavaScript code has to know what value to use for "display" for each div.  Usually, it's "block," "inline," or "grid."  This information ought to be in the CSS, not in the JavaScript.

I tried using jquery.show() and jquery.hide(), but that always results in display being set to "block" if it starts out as "none."  I was hoping that there was some way in CSS to indicate a div's proper value for when it's not "none."  But I haven't found anything like that.

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: how about `.addClass(...)` and `.removeClass(...)` ? Then each class can have the `display` values you wish

Comment: You'd probably want to share with us what you think you might want to use. As you can see, some people have ideas, and they get downvoted because others don't see the same way. This isn't really a good website to ask for opinions.

Comment: Can't reproduce -> https://jsfiddle.net/zkqwjc9k/

Comment: In fact, the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/show/) explictly states that *"...the display property is restored to whatever it was initially. If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline"*, so jQuery restores the display property, and elements that natively have other display properties than `block` will be restored.

Comment: wrap the element you need with a block div and it will work the jquery hide/show. Just <div class="hideshow"><yourelements></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more elegant solution would be working with classes.

As you said, the `display` information is in your CSS file. The solution that's easiest and most readable is to add a `.hidden` class to elements that should be hidden.

In your CSS file:

```
.hidden {display: none;}
```

Toggle class in jQuery:

```
// Equivalent of hide():
$(el).addClass("hidden")

// Equivalent of show():
$(el).removeClass("hidden")
```

You don't have to add anything more. No additional CSS rules or anything. If you're working with specific rules you may want to add `!important`. I think this is one of those cases where its usage is justified, i.e.:

```
.hidden {display: none !important;}
```

Now all elements will get hidden if they have the `hidden` class, even if their selector is more specific.

Comment: First, I really appreciate all the input.  Well, except for the inevitable “you’ve asked a bad question” commentary.

I’m accepting this answer, because it seems to be the cleanest.  That’s because the styling information stays in CSS where it belongs.  That’s better than having HTML/JS that knows that the proper “display” value for a certain div is “grid.”

It’s not perfect, because the HTML still needs to know that a certain div is going to start out hidden.  It would be nice to keep that information in CSS. 
 But I think this is the best we can do with the current version of CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You could just directly use

```
$(whatever).css('display', 'what you want');
```

Removing the inline style attribute would be something like the other question: [Use jQuery to remove an inline style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790795/use-jquery-to-remove-an-inline-style)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the css display initial to recover the original display of the element (inline or Block).

```
$('#some-id').css('display', 'initial');
```

Comment: Setting a non-inherited property like `display` to `inherit` doesn't make a lot of sense. `display: initial` might be more appropriate, although [that value isn't supported by IE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-initial-value).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If you set a non compatible display element on old IE, the IE return to initial display type.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#element').show();
%('#element').css('display','inline')
```

or

```
$('#element').addClass('show');
```

in stylesheet:

```
.show{
   display: inline;
}
```

Either should work fine. I don't know of any other way.